# Load MySQL Data into Corresponding PHP Variables

Tags: php, mysql

I got this work for me, but I'm sure there's a better way to get this done. But, I've searched many hours without finding the exact answer to what I'm looking to do. Basically getting the variable usrID from the URL, I need to search MySQL for the corresponding information to this user. Later I want to use the different fields on my page (better website) to personalize the experience.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "authorized-user";
$password = "secret";
$dbname = "agentDB";
$usrID = "001";


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM agentInfo WHERE usrID = '$usrID'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $Lname = $row["Lname"];
    $Fname = $row["Fname"];
    $tl = $row["tl"];
        }
} 
mysqli_close($conn);
?> 

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Load MySQL Data into Corresponding PHP Variables</title>
</head>

<body>
here is the body<br>
My name is: <?php echo $Fname; ?> <?php echo $Lname; ?><?php echo $tl; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but your assigning a static variable to `$usrID`

Comment: just for this purpose here. I have a lot more code above and below, but this is where I believe I can do better

Comment: well you can always place your db connections on a header file that you include on pages where you use the database.

Comment: Thanks. How about loading the table row data into their corresponding fields as php variables

Comment: I like your approach. 'Extract' is one alternative, but it's widely criticised

Comment: The most efficient way to do it other than the one you are using is [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php). In a controlled environment such as this (where the only variables will be named columns from a table) there shouldn't be any risks associated with it. However you might want to protect yourself even more by specifying the column names in your query instead of using `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable to store a full name and then "tl" on it like this:

```
$user_info = $Lname . ", " . $Fname . ": " . $tl;
```

Then:

```
<?php echo $user_info; ?>
```

Wherever you need that information.

If you want to minimize the amount of variables being assigned you could wrap it in a function and return the desired data field:

```
function fetchUserData(userData) {
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM agentInfo WHERE usrID = '$usrID'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $userData = $row[userData];
        }
    }
    return $userData;
} 
mysqli_close($conn);
```

You can the get the specified data like this:

```
<?php echo fetchUserData("Fname"); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was mainly looking for the best way to assign each individual database field query result to individual php variables so that I can use to produce dynamic personalized content throughout the website. There are close to 40 fields that would need to be assigned to 40 php variables

Comment: Oh. If that's the case then really you're already making it work rather efficiently. If you're trying to create maintainable code for a long-term project then I'd suggest throwing all of your query logic into another file and doing <?php include("../path/to/my/file); ?> at the top of the page. Then you won't have your data logic mixed too heavily with your view logic.